# UI no response due to __psynch_mutexwait

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, deadlock

My app sometimes becomes `dead` , and the call stack is like below,

---

Update:

[image]

[image]

---

[image]

[image]

I've spent two days but could not handle it yet.

What I have are contexts for each thread, and one retained context for a special serial queue.

What I am wondered about is that how the deadlock comes. `Why all the threads are in waiting states?` Just one possibility will be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please provide the full backtrace for all threads. You can get that by running `bt all` or `backtrace all` in the debugger when the deadlock happens. Press the pause button in the debugger which activates the LLDB console and you can see the entire backtrace there by running the above commands.

Answer (score 1):

That happens some times when doing work in a notification handler that may result in other notifications being sent, easiest way to avoid it is to dispatch_async the work that needs to be done.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
    // The work that needs to be done...
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you give me more detail considering the call stack above? What kind of notification may be sent? mocDidSave?

Comment: @JasonLee I can't really tell without all the full backtraces but a moc sends 3 different notifications willSave, didSave and didChange.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when one tries to access Core Data objects on a background thread using the main-threads context **OR** using the same managed object context on different threads (background or main) at the same time. For more details check out [Core Data concurrency rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001182-SW39).

So to avoid both cases, the main rule is, each thread must have its own managed object context and initialize that context exactly where it's going to be used.

For example:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

   //
   // Prepare your background core data context
   // 

   if (self.privateContext == nil)
   {
       self.privateContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
       [self.privateContext setParentContext: - main managed object context - ];
       [self.privateContext setUndoManager:nil]; // this context should not manage undo actions.
   }

   //
   //   Do any Core Data requests using this thread-save context
   //

   .
   .
   .

});
```